# Mac Terminal: Edit Text Document

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, shortcut

I‘m again trying to make a siri-shortcut which let you run applications on your Mac.

https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/f74c9bd89f1a4e71a3e8f72da5cf5ab7

It's making a list of all your applications in a text document, but there is the text document self also in the list. Can I delete the name of the document in this list with a command and without using keyboard?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like what you were thinking with the screenshots, but (with the exception of the one that shows the commands you're running over SSH) I don't think they're helping to support your _real_ question which is, fundamentally, "how do I list a directory, redirect that list into a file, but prevent the **list file itself** from showing up in the listing?"

Answer (score 4):

`ls > Applications.txt` is going to list the `Applications.txt` file in the list.

Though I don't entirely understand all of your workflow, adding the `-d` flag should do the trick, by specifying *.app.

```bsh
ls -d *.app > Applications.txt
```

Just like your previous approach though, that won't catch .app files buried in subdirectories (like your Adobe Suite). You can modify find's maxdepth parameter for something like that:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*.app" > Applications.txt
```

If you wish to search within *all* subdirectories of the current one, simply omit the `-maxdepth` option altogether.

If you have a problem with the pathname being part of the output (*e.g.*, you want `Terminal.app` not `./Utilities/Terminal.app`), then try this instead:

```bsh
cd /Applications
find * -type d -name "*.app" -exec basename "{}" \; > Applications.txt
```

If you want to find *any* application *anywhere* on your Mac, try:

```bsh
mdfind -interpret "kind:application"  # this is localized for your language
```

The `mdfind` command uses Spotlight's index, so it's fast, but (being an index) it may not always represent the *exact*, up-to-the-minute state of the filesystem. How to remove the pathname from the front is left as an exercise for the reader (*hint*: `xargs -I{} basename "{}"`).

Comment: There are just the .app files in the text document. Is there also a command which list all .app files like Adobe Photoshop CC 2019.app?

Comment: @JonathanXD12 See dxdc's updated answer. The `find` command, or the `mdfind` command (which uses the Mac's Spotlight index) are probably better tools for the job than `ls`.

Comment: Increasing the `maxdepth` might be good enough-   ` find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -name '*.app' -exec basename {} \;  > FILE`

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to avoid the problem altogether by creating the text file outside the Applications folder. This will also make
sure that the workflow works for users without write access there. In the SSH action use

```
cd /Applications
ls > ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~is~workflow~my~workflows/Documents/Applications/Applications.txt
```

to create the file directly at the place you want it to end up.